# Variable assignment in the constructor

Tags: python, constructor, variable-assignment

I have a question to the variable assignment in the constructor: I have a constructer which takes the argument 'context'. First, I assign this variable to a class variable. Second, I create another class which also takes 'context' as an argument.

To my question: Is it better to assignment the class variable (self.context) or the argument from the constructor (context) to the new created class?

```
class State():
    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context           
        self.diconnected = Disconnected(self.context)
```

or

```
class State():
        def __init__(self, context):
            self.context = context           
            self.diconnected = Disconnected(context)
```

Comment: Those are instance variables, not class variables.

Comment: Sorry for the confussion. I meant instance variables of course

Answer (score 2):

The end result is the same. `Disconnected(context)` is just slightly shorter and faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not going to effect your program execution time in any significant way in Python. The only situation this could matter is when multiple threads may be using this data. I'd always use the argument just in case.

Comment: To clarify: A thread could intrrupt between the assignment (self.context = context) and the use of the self.context as argument and therefore lead to an invalid state?

Comment: It could change the value of self.context before it was passed to the second class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

None is objectively "better"; you're passing the same object to `Disconnected` in any case.

Which one you write depends on which dependency you want to emphasize: that `Disconnected` has the same context as `self` (which also implies that `self` always has one), or that it has the context passed in as the parameter.